# Javascript: Как получить данные с задержкой?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Есть код, который получает данные из json. Нужно подгружать данные с небольшой задержкой, положим полсекунды. Как это реализовать?

```js
function getPosts() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'data/post.json');
        xhr.onload = function(evt) {
            var rawData = evt.target.response;
            var loadedPosts = JSON.parse(rawData);
            posts = loadedPosts;

            //отрисовка данных
            renderPosts(loadedPosts);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

И если вызвать функцию getPost() таким образом, задержки нет все равно..

```js
  setTimeout(getPosts(), 500);
```

Comment: `setTimeout(getPosts, 500);` без скобок

Comment: @АлексейШиманский оформили бы как ответ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо большое, буду знать тонкости такие, все получилось) да, отметьте как ответ, мб другим новичкам в будущем пригодится)

Comment: @b-ars07 не пригодится - они просто не найдут его в поиске

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если почитать [описание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), то увидим следующее:

Синтаксис: `var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);`, где

- timeoutID - это числовой ID, который может быть использован позже с window.clearTimeout().
- func - это функция, которую требуется вызвать после delay миллисекунд.
- code - в альтернативном варианте применения это строка, содержащая код, который вы хотите выполнить после delay миллисекунд (использовать этот метод не рекомендуется по тем же причинам, что и eval())
- delay -  задержка в миллисекундах (тысячных долях секунды), после которой будет выполнен вызов функции. Реальная задержка может быть больше; см. Notes ниже.

И увидим примеры написания:

```
window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 2000);
```

---

Соответственно, вызвать функцию можно либо записав строкой (но это не рекомендуется):

```
setTimeout("getPosts()", 500);
```

либо передать имя вызывающей функции, но без круглых скобок:

```
setTimeout(getPosts, 500);
```

т.к. логично, что круглые скобки в конце имени функции заставят её выполнится.

Answer (score 0):

Так же нашел такой способ вызова setTimeout для функции с параметрами:

```js
function foo(param1, param2) {
  //some code
}

........
setTimeout(function() {foo(param1, param2}, 500);
```

Может кому понадобится.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status == 200) {
        successHandler && successHandler(xhr.response);
    } else {
        errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
    }
```

Вариант без таймаута